# Text of Text View will not align center due to increase in characters of Text in Android?

Tags: android

I have text view align **bottom - center** of the image view. when i have a less characters it will show properly align-center of image view as show in picture.[image]

But if i have a more no. of characters it will not align-center of image view like show in picture below[image]

i want to align text center even if it contain more characters. i have added my code below.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/meme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="BOTTOM TEXT"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:gravity="center" add this line inside your textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below Code:  That contains  **android:gravity="center"** which will make text in view as center. No problem how much characters!!!!!!!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/meme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="BOTTOM TEXT BOTTOM TEXT BOTTOM TEXT"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

That specifies:

*Specifies how to align the text by the view's x- and/or y-axis when the text is smaller than the view.* You can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:gravity)